# Multidimensional Principal Component Analysis

Tags: pca, dataset, functional-data-analysis

I found a lot of question about principal component analysis as well as functional PCA but only in the sense of time series and not in spatial case and multidimensional principal component analysis. So I hope my question is valid here:

If i have 3D tensor data, i.e. n images with p1 x p2 pixels. Thus my 3D tensor data is $X\epsilon R^{nxp1xp2}$.

If i calculate a rank approximation like in Allen (1990): http://signalprocessingsociety.org/CAMSAP2013/papers/1569807425.pdf

$ min_X \|X−\hat{X} \|$ with   $\hat{X} =∑_{k=1}^K d_k * u_ k \otimes v_k \otimes w_k, $

I get: $X \approx \sum^K_{k=1} d_k * u_k \otimes v_k \otimes w_k$.

If i want to use this for principal component regression, can I use $ PC=d_k * u_k$ as my principal component scores like in a standard principal component regression?

Comment: Yes. As long the underlaying data are not sparse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Can I interpret the d_k as my eigenvalues corresponding to the multivariate PCA? And thus the u_k, v_k and w_k as the corresponding eigenfunctions?

Comment: The paper is much more related to SVD so I would assume those are singular values rather than eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks again. I have still some problems with understanding for instance why it should not work for sparse data. Can you give a short explanation or refer to a paper?

Comment: The short answer is that if the data is sparse, the numerical integration step ($\int_T Y_i(t) -\mu(t)) \phi(t) dt$) we require to get the FPC scores will be a bad approximation.